# Importing the database content along with the code..

Tags: python, mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-python

I have written a code in Python which accesses Mysql database in my computer.My question is how do I make my program run on other machines i.e how do I transfer the database ??
Thank you for reading...

Comment: Look into export/import mysql database.

Comment: Depends are you really looking to export the database or just connect to it?  If just looking to export jojo's answer is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the tools that come with MYSQL installation 
from command line

backup

```
mysqldump -u root -p pass21 --databases yourdb > multibackup.sql
```

restore

```
mysql -u sadmin -p pass21 Customers < multibackup.sql
```

[Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database/1/)